# How to mute windows beep sound in SSMS 18.5 everytime you tab in the table designer?

Tags: sql-server, windows, ssms

Each time I use the table designer and the focus changes from any field (Column Name, Data Type, Allow Nulls, etc.) either by pressing the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key or switching to another window, the classic windows beep sound plays. And it's annoying as heck, whoever decided it was a good idea should revisit his objective in life.

SSMS (SQL Management Studio) doesn't even appear in the volume mixer, so I can't even mute it from there unless I mute the entire output device (or System sounds) which isn't what I want. Is anybody else experiencing this or is it happening only on my computer?

Comment: Maybe ask on https://superuser.com/

Comment: @darkguy definitely the same issue! too much annoying! Please inform me if you find any solution

Comment: @ozz I did find one but it involved muting Windows's Asterisk sound. Sucks, but it works. See my question here -> https://superuser.com/questions/1544034/how-to-mute-windows-beep-sound-in-ssms-18-5-everytime-you-tab-in-the-table-desig . I've also published it as a bug in UserVoice, it'd be a great help if you can upvote it to get attention. Thanks! -> https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/40318435--confirmed-bug-ssms-18-2-ok-18-3-1-bug